# AngularJS - Quando devo utilizar ng-show e quando devo utilizar ng-hide?

Tags: angularjs

Estou vendo um tutorial, e em um certo momento ele apresenta o código dizendo que o mais correto é utilizar o ng-hide na tag DIV e mais abaixo na tag BUTTON o mesmo utilizou ng-show. Quando devo utilizar cada um deles?

```
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
<div ng-show="!store.product.soldOut">
    <h1> {{store.product.name}} </h1>
    <h2> ${{store.product.price}} </h2>
    <p> {{store.product.description}} </p>
    <button ng-show="store.product.canPurchase">Add to Cart </button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: `ng-show="!store.product.soldOut"` equivale a `ng-hide="store.product.soldOut"` .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

De modo bem simples:

- `ng-show`: quando você quiser exibir um conteúdo com alguma condição;
- `ng-hide`: quando você quiser esconder um conteúdo com alguma condição;

Caso 01: Exibir uma div quando o valor de `nome` for `Pedro`

```
<div ng-show="nome == 'Pedro'"> </div>
```

Caso 02: Esconder uma div quando valor de `idade` for menor que 18:

```
<div ng-hide="idade < 18"> </div>
```

No Caso 01, a `div` só será exibida se o valor de nome for "Pedro", se for qualquer outro valor, seja ele válido ou não, ela nunca será exibida. O mesmo acontece para o Caso 02, porém com a lógica inversa. A `div` sempre será exibida, no entanto, se a idade for menor que 18, ela **não** será exibida.

#### Observação importante

O que você deve estar ciente ao usar `ng-show` e/ou `ng-hide` é que a `div` (ou qualquer outro elemento usando as propriedades) ainda irá existir em seu `html`. O efeito deles é de apenas controlar a exibição através da propriedade `css display` mudando `display:hidden` quando precisar excluir.

Em contra partida, existe o `ng-if`, ele funciona de modo semelhante, veja:

```
<div ng-if="nome == 'Pedro'"></div>
```

Neste caso a `div` só será exibida se o valor de nome for Pedro.

**Mas então, qual a diferença?**

O `ng-if` não vai renderizar a `div` em seu `html` enquanto o valor não for "Pedro", ou seja, ela não existe em seu `html`.

Comment: +1 - Vale lembrar que usando `ng-if` objetos no DOM são destruídos/reconstruídos, enquanto que `ng-show` e `ng-hide` apenas controlam visibilidade. Importante se custos de reconstrução ou garantia de estado para `controllers` for um ponto crítico.

Comment: Bem lembrado @lbotinelly